# get HD photo of contact in android

Tags: android, photo, contacts

I want fetch the contact's HD photo in android, but I can only get to a resolution of 96x96.  I am using a Android 4.0 phone and I have set the HD photo.  When I called, the HD photo appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo contains the contact's primary photo. The photo may be stored in up to two ways - the default "photo" is a thumbnail-sized image stored directly in the data row, while the "display photo", if present, is a larger version stored as a file.

For more details please refer this link
[http://ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html)